# Formatting date method returns wrong month

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have function which format my startDate and endDate in format 'mm dd yyyy'.

Problem is cus every time this function return one month lower:

```
const formatingDate = (dates) => {
  const d = new Date(dates);
  return `${d
    .getMonth()
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, '0')}/${d
    .getDate()
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
};
```

This is argument for method `formattingDate()`

> [Wed Jul 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
>   Thu Aug 01 2019 23:59:59 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)]

How to fix this formattingDate() function to return right month?

Comment: Months are zero based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS month range is from 0-11. So you have to add 1 to month.

```js
const formatingDate = (dates) => {
    const d = new Date(dates);
    return `${(d.getMonth() + 1)
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, '0')}/${d
        .getDate()
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
};

console.log(formatingDate('2019-07-24'))
```

[**Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth#Return_value).

Comment: Did not help... Thanks

Comment: If I this `d.getMonth() + (1).toString()` as result get this date:  https://prnt.sc/ojdfsz

Comment: Yes, I notice, updated the answer.

Comment: Also, please vote to close as there are many many duplicates for this.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this document

[getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Months are from 0 to n-1